# How to the write SQL to show the data in my case in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, matrix

I have a table like this -

```
create table tbl1 
(
id number,
role number
);


insert into tbl1 values (1, 1);
insert into tbl1 values (2, 3);
insert into tbl1 values (1, 3);


create table tbl2
(
role number,
meaning varchar(50)
);

insert into tbl2 values (1, 'changing data');
insert into tbl2 values (2, 'move file');
insert into tbl2 values (3, 'dance');
```

I want the sql result like the following -

```
id     role_meaning      is_permitted
1      changing data     yes
1      move file         no
1      dance             yes
2      changing data     no
2      move file         no
2      dance             yes
```

Please help how can I do this? I have tried several methods but not sure how to do this.

Comment: Whence is the data in your `is_permitted` column?  Tables `tbl1` and `tbl2` don't seem to have it.

Comment: hi, this should be determined from the 'tbl1' table (if the value is 1 then yes, if not present in the table then no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [partitioned outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) here.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54c8cb/5)

**Query 1**:

```
select tbl1.id,
tbl2.meaning,
case when tbl1.role is NULL then 'no' else 'yes' end is_permitted
from tbl1 
partition by (id) right outer join tbl2
on tbl1.role = tbl2.role
order by tbl1.id, tbl2.role
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54c8cb/5/0)**:

```
| ID |       MEANING | IS_PERMITTED |
|----|---------------|--------------|
|  1 | changing data |          yes |
|  1 |     move file |           no |
|  1 |         dance |          yes |
|  2 | changing data |           no |
|  2 |     move file |           no |
|  2 |         dance |          yes |
```